# Terraform provider Azure - how to change ASC Default `PARAMETERS` in Azure policy?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

What is the correct and easy way of changing ASC Default `PARAMETERS` in Azure policy using TF?

As an example Set `Monitor SQL Encryption` to `AuditIfNotExists` or any other available value than `Disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

'ASC Default' is initiative, or so called azurerm_policy_set_definition in TF terms. You just need to assign it using 'azurerm_policy_assignment'.

These links might help:

1. https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policySetDefinitions/Security%20Center/AzureSecurityCenter.json
2. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/policy_assignment

Example for different initiative:

```
  resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "audit_k8s_security_restricted_standarts" {
  name = "42b8ef37-b724-4e24-bbc8-7a7708edfe00"
  scope = local.azure_policy_scope
  policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/42b8ef37-b724-4e24-bbc8-7a7708edfe00"
  description = "This initiative includes the policies for the Kubernetes cluster pod security restricted standards."
  display_name = "Kubernetes cluster pod security restricted standards for Linux-based workloads"
  identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }
  location = var.primary_location
  parameters = <<PARAMETERS
    {
      "effect": {
        "value": "audit"
      }
    }
    PARAMETERS
}
```

What you need is to place proper policy_definition_id and pass valid parameters. And start small, with one simple param, there are bugs in TF.